# Match a string with number but only if there is > in front of the number

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have HTML:

```
<div id="ingredients">
    <p itemprop="ingredients">30 dag beans</p>
    <p itemprop="ingredients">around 1,5 liter of water </p>
</div>
```

I have javascript:

```
$('#ingredients').html(
    function (i, text) {
        return text.replace(/>([\d,]+)/g, '<span>$1</span>');
    });
```

The regular expression should replace the first number with 'test' because before the number there is > tag. It should not replace the second number (we use , for number decimals) because there is space before.

So I'd like it to replace only the ingredients that have number at the beggining of the paragraph, not the ones that have numbers in the middle of the paragraph.

Why does it not work? If I omit the > in the regex it works, but replaces all the numbers even the ones in the middle of the sentance.

Comment: start < and end tag > do not feature in the values `.html()`

Comment: **Code:** `$('#ingredients p').html(function(i, text) {
  return text.trim().replace(/^([\d,]+)/, '<span>$1</span>');
});` [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/cgLwu81g/)

Comment: Ohhh, that is the problem. How do I do it then?

Comment: Tushar, thank you! So simple solution and I tortured myself so much with it. I console.log the html of the selector and it showed html also. How do I give you credit for the answer, as it is in comment only?

Comment: @Tushar will have to post it as an answer and then you credit him, if he wants the points :p

Comment: @Jerry2 Do you want to match `1,4 bags` too? or just `1 bag of ...`.

Comment: I want to match 1,4 bags also

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **problem** with your regex is that it is also replacing `>` of the `<p>`.

This can be solved by using

```
return text.replace(/>([\d,]+)/g, '><span>$1</span>');
                                   ^
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/cgLwu81g/2/) and [**Regex101 Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/jA9zH2/1)

but there is better way to do this.

---

**Steps:**

1. Iterate over all the `<p>` elements inside the container `#ingredients`
2. Get the innerHTML of the current paragraph element inside loop
3. `trim` the spaces
4. Use regex `^([\d,]+)` to extract the numbers that are at the beginning of the string and replace it by `<span>$1</span>`, `$1` here is the number that is captured by the regex.

**Regex Explanation:**

1. `^`: Start of the line
2. `([\d,]+)`: First capturing group. Matching one or more occurrences of number and/or comma in any sequence. This captured group can be accessed by using `$1`.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/cgLwu81g/) and [**Regex101 Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/jA9zH2/2)

```js
// Iterate over all the paragraph elements inside the container
$('#ingredients p[itemprop="ingredients"]').html(function(index, text) {
  // text == innerText of the current `p` element

  // The value returned will be replaced to the innerHTML
  // First trim the string to remove leading and trailing spaces
  return text.trim().replace(/^([\d,]+)/, '<span>$1</span>');
});
```

```css
span {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ingredients">
  <p itemprop="ingredients">30 dag beans</p>
  <p itemprop="ingredients">around 1,5 liter of water</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `/g` needed I think or it will only match one time.

Comment: @ShanShan Global flag is not needed here, since there'll be only one number at the beginning of line. Also note that I'm looping over `p` element inside the container and not the container itself.

Comment: Oh right, you changed the selector, it's better that way.

Comment: I have updated the question with one more thing, I'd like the regex to return the "number + dag" or "number + g" or just number and put the rest in another span...

Comment: Doesn't work because I need to exclude the (dag|g) from the group. If I omit ?: then it is even worse as the $2 gets the value dag or g ;-( Problems seems to be it never comes to the (.)* part, only first part is swapped, $2 is empty string.

Comment: @Jerry2 Can you show an example input string and expected output

Comment: @Jerry2 Check [`^([\d,]+)\s(dag|g)?(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/fC2cF9/3). I saw update but still not clear to me what you are expecting.

Comment: I updated the question, in the end I have the regex string and the expected output.